# How to press Alt Gr in Parallels Desktop?

Tags: keyboard, parallels-desktop

I have a MacBook Air and I run Windows Vista as a Parallels Desktop guest. In Windows I need to press <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> but I don't have that key on my MacBook Air.

How can I press Alt Gr in Parallels Desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [article on macosxhints](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060914024254779) you can press ctrl-alt to get AltGr.
Sometimes that doesn't work, so you'll have to remap your keys under windows, which is described in the linked to article.

There's also [this article on Parallels' forums](http://forum.parallels.com/thread5493.html) which suggests you do this:

> 1. Stop any running VMs, close all instances of Parallels Desktop for Mac.
> 2. Launch “Macintosh HD” - “Applications” – “Utilities” – “Terminal”.
> 3. Type the following commands in Terminal (without quotes), please mind that the system might ask you for the Administrator password after each command – type it and hit Enter:
> 4. “sudo touch /Library/Parallels/.keyboard_config”
> 5. “sudo chmod 666 /Library/Parallels/.keyboard_config”
> 6. “sudo echo "numenterisaltgr" > /Library/Parallels/.keyboard_config”
> 7. Close the Terminal.
> 8. Launch Parallels Desktop for Mac and check Right Enter key behavior in VM – everything should work as you’ve set.

Comment: Yes, it's really buggy - sometimes Ctrl+Alt works and a few seconds later it doesn't work.

Comment: The problem is that MacBook Air is a laptop and I don't have a *right enter* key.

Comment: Thanks, the instructions in your first link worked fine.